Movie that is extremely similar to Afflicted
I'm looking for a movie released after 2012.
An American guy gets fired from his job at a local bar. His mother just died and he decides to take some vacation.
The movie is set in Italy, a very popular tourist spot where he meets an extremely attractive (no sure about her nationality) redhead girl, she in facts is hiding a secret, she is a vampire and has to kill from time to time to be able to preserve her human appearance.
He takes a job at a farm where an italian 70-years old farmer tells him the story about his late wife.
At the end, she doesn't turn into a horrible creature because she falls in love with him and that was the only cure.
I also remember that first he is with some english guys and they leave italy because the hostel they're staying at it's too expensive.
Any thoughts?
UPDATE: I remember watching it on Netflix.

You're looking for Spring from 2014.

A young man in a personal tailspin flees the US to Italy, where he sparks up a romance with a woman harboring a dark, primordial secret.

Everything you've described is in there (he falls in love with a redheaded vampire, and in the end it's their love that makes her mortal). Here's the trailer:



